# How to build a WAR file with gradle?

Tags: gradle

I want to build a WAR file (and then deploy it to Tomcat). So, as an exercise, I've started a new Spring Boot Project using Gradle in IDEA IntelliJ. Afterwards, I've apply the plugin in the `build.gradle` file, like this `apply plugin: 'war'`
.

The problem is that when I try to run `gradle war` in the terminal, I get no war file! The only thing that happens is that it will generate a `\build` with 3 subsolders `classes`, `resources` and `tmp`, but there's no WAR in these.

What should I do to get a WAR file? I've watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05EKZ9Xmfws) video, but this guy uses Maven and doesn't do advanced stuff and gets the war. I think there's got to be a way to keep it simple.

When I run `gradle war --info`

> ```
> Initialized native services in: C:\Users\...\.gradle\native The client
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   Resolving global dependency management for project 'deleteme'
>   Excluding [org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api]
>   Excluding []
>   Skipping task ':compileJava' as it is up-to-date.
>   :compileJava (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.753 secs.
>   :processResources (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.
>
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Skipping task ':processResources' as it is up-to-date.
>   :processResources (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
>   :classes (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.
>
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
>   Skipping task ':classes' as it has no actions.
>   :classes (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
>   :war (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.
>
> Task :war SKIPPED
>   Skipping task ':war' as task onlyIf is false.
>   :war (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.

Comment: `gradle war` should generate the war in `/build/libs` directory

Comment: I know, but it isn't there. Can you try to see if this works for you?

Comment: Can you share the logs on the terminal when you run `gradle war` ?

Comment: try zipping the `classes`, `resources` and `tmp` folders into a single `.zip` file, then rename it to a `.war` file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess that you have applied the spring boot gradle plugin to your project, in addition to the war plugin ?  then this behaviour is normal, since the Spring Boot plugin will disable *jar* and *war* tasks and replace these with *bootWar* and *bootJar* tasks .

With both spring boot and war plugin applied:

```
./gradlew war
15:35:09: Executing task 'war'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :war SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
15:35:10: Task execution finished 'war'.
```

Note the *SKIPPED* message

```
$ ./gradlew bootWar
15:36:35: Executing task 'bootWar'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootWar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
15:36:37: Task execution finished 'bootWar'.
```

Then you will get the expected *war* file under *build/libs*.

You can still re-enable the standard jar/war tasks as explained here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-wars-deployable   (if you need to produce normal archives and not executable archives)

Regarding the Tomcat issue: install Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: And what should I modify to get a WAR?

Comment: you need to call 'bootWar' task, I have edited my answer.

Comment: in fact it depends on what kind of archive you want to produce: if you need an executable jar/war, just use the spring boot tasks bootWar/bootJar. If you want a normal archive, then you can enable jar/war tasks as explained here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-wars-deployable

Comment: I've got a WAR without including the closure `war{enabled=true}` but it can't be deployed to Tomcat. And if I try to add the closure it gives me: > Could not find method war() for arguments [build_20hpmyk1gg89gy3gwioursjxu$_run_closure1@117145] on root project 'delete
me' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: I think this link can help you : https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-war-to-tomcat  .  If you need to deploy the war to Tomcat, you need to produce a "normal" deployable war, not a "executable" (boot)war. So you will need to enable the war task with  *war{ enable=true}" (this requires that you apply the war plugin : *apply plugin 'war: "

Comment: catalina says: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)

Comment: Thanks, but now it says: SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/deleteme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180003/discussion-between-m-ricciuti-and-mateut-alin).

Answer (score 7):

Please read: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

If using Gradle with IntelliJ, goto build.gradle (or build.gradle.kts for Kotlin) and add

> id 'war'

(or just

> war

for Kotlin ) under Plugins

Reload Gradle Project and then use gradlew bootWar on the Intellij Terminal.

Add --info or --stackTrace for debugging

Answer (score 4):

As rightly said by @M.Ricciuti, the spring boot gradle plugin will disable the `jar/war` tasks and would only work with `bootJar/bootWar` tasks. But if you still want your project to be packaged with `jar/war` tasks just add the below to your `build.gradle` file

```
war {
    enabled=true
}
```

This would enable the `gradle war` command to generate the war for your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot with gradle, you should follow the steps below:

1. Edit your build.gradle file adding `apply plugin:'war'` and then rebuild gradle.
2. With gradle built two (2) files will be created on your root directory:
   `gradlew` (for Linux) and `gradlew.bat` (for windows)

Open your terminal on your current project and run
`./gradlew war`

Your project will build and generate a `.war` file in `build/libs/`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.

After a lot of struggle, I figured out that I needed to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` in my application. So my effective code looks like

```
    public class SyncApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SyncApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SyncApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Looks like this `SpringBootServletInitializer` directs war plugins generate bootstrapping code while building the war, and thus spring context is initialized while deploying the app.