# Change mongo dbname through build script

Tags: spring, mongodb, gradle

What do I want:
I want to set up an automated deployment pipeline -  my plan is as follows:
I create two `.war` files, let's call them `prod.war` and `test.war`, using a gradle build script, and deploy them to my tomcat server.

My problem:
The `prod.war` needs to access the production database (`mongoprod`), and the `test.war` to the test database (`mongotest`).

My attempt:
I thought I could use Spring profiles and simply...

1. ...change a line in my `application-context.xml` from:
   `<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="mongoprod"/>`
   to:
   `<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.db.name}"/>`
2. ...create two files, in the same folder (`<filename>`:`<content`>):
   `application-production.properties`:`mongo.db.name=mongotest`
   `application-test.properties`:`mongo.db.name=mongoprod`
3. ...execute some gradle build script with an argument that can change the profile to `production` or `test` and then use the corresponding `.property` file to insert the desired mongo dbname...but that's where I ran out of luck!
   I tried to add this to my `build.gradle` file:
   `bootRun { args = ["--spring.profiles.active=" + profiles] }`
   and then run it with `$ ./gradlew bootRun -Ptest`
   but I just get the error:
   `Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved`
   and besides that I haven't used `bootRun` before, only a `war` task so far to create my `.war` files:
   `war {
           archiveName = 'application.war'
           dependsOn 'lessc', 'webpack'
           from "$buildDir/webapp"
           exclude 'WEB-INF/js/main.js'
           rename 'main\\.min\\.js', 'main.js'
       }`

Does anyone know how I can get my problem to work or could give me useful information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that for my case it turned out to be much easier (and I think better) to decide during runtime wether a test or a production DB should be used and I solved it the following way:
In my `application-context.xml` I created two beans instead of one, one for each DB (I had to nest them below a "root"-beans, otherwise I got errors during building):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd">

    <beans profile="prod">
        <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="mongoprod"/>

        <mongo:mapping-converter id="mongoConverter" base-package="my.company.project">
            <mongo:custom-converters base-package="my.company.project"/>
        </mongo:mapping-converter>

        <mongo:gridFsTemplate bucket="images" converter-ref="mongoConverter" db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="test">
        <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="mongotest"/>

        <mongo:mapping-converter id="mongoConverter" base-package="my.company.project">
            <mongo:custom-converters base-package="my.company.project"/>
        </mongo:mapping-converter>

        <mongo:gridFsTemplate bucket="images" converter-ref="mongoConverter" db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

In order for the .war file creation to work properly I had to set `enabled` to `true` in my build.gradle file here:

```
war {
    enabled = true //without this no .war file was created before - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315049/4120196
    dependsOn 'lessc', 'webpack'
    from "$buildDir/webapp"
    exclude 'WEB-INF/js/main.js'
    rename 'main\\.min\\.js', 'main.js'
}
```

I then created a .war file, copied it and renamed it - so I had two: `prod.war` and `test.war` and put them into my `Tomcat 8.5_Tomcat8.5.23\webapps` folder (I'm working on Win10 in case this differs on other systems). Then I created two .xml files with the same name as the .war files where I defined the spring profile that decides which bean to take in `Tomcat 8.5_Tomcat8.5.23\conf\Catalina\localhost`:
`prod.xml`

```
<Context>
  <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="prod" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
</Context>
```

`test.xml`

```
<Context>
  <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="test" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
</Context>
```

I started up tomcat and finally everything worked as I wanted it to.

If you have any hints how my solution can be improved feel free to comment :)
I feel like my application-context.xml could be shortened somehow for example...

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a main class name to be run by the `bootRun` task, for example as follows:

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'org.baeldung.DemoApplication'
}
```

You can read more about it in thos [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class)

**Update:**

configuration for application plugin could be done as follows

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'org.gradle.sample.Main'
}
```

As it's said in the [plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_usage)

Comment: I think the problem is, that my application is not a spring boot application - so what do you think is easier - turn it into one or solve it another way?

Comment: @Cold_Class if you are using an application plugin, not a spring boot, you can directly configure it. I've updated my answer with the example from the plugin docs. Actually, springboot lugin uses application plugin undecover, so the configuration is mostly the same

Comment: I don't know what to put into mainClassName - and now I don't need to use `$ ./gradlew bootRun -Ptest` anymore, I tried using `application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['--spring.profiles.active=' + profiles]
}` and then $  ./gradlew but I get the error `Could not find method application() for arguments [build_3ifqsajbiowbv9gepih3q5dfd$_run_closure10@10f5bd4] on root project`

Comment: I just wonder, you are running a `bootRun` task, which is a part of the `spring-boot-plugin`. SpringBoot app as a standalone runnable is executed via main method of some class. `BootRun` is just running this main method of the so called `mainClass`. How could it be, that it's not a SpringBoot application, but the plugin you are applied is for SpringBoot? If it's not a SpringBootm you can't use this plugin to run your app. May be you have to find out another way to run your app.

Comment: May be via a native application plugin and it's `run` task. But for that you need to change a plugin, removing `spring-boot-plugin` and applying `application. Here is an explanation of this plugin  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get far with all of this - I think it is because I still don't understand how gradle + plugins + spring are working together. But I found an alternative solution that suit my needs (see my own answer).
Thank you for your input!